# Split pandas series by index names, integer index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas series of this format with multiple non unique indexes (example)

```
    index value   
      num     1
        0     2
      num     3
        0     4
```

and would like to split it into 2 series:

```
    index value          index value
      num     1              0     2
      num     3              0     4
```

The order of the values has to be maintained as in the example( order as they appear in the list). The first can just be obtained by

```
series.num
```

or

```
series['num']
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work for the second one as the indexes are integers. Anybody has a solution to this?

Comment: I haven't used the function myself, so I can't provide an answer, but you may be able to accomplish what you want using this: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use .iloc[] to locate the rows by index:

```
df1 = df.iloc[df.index == 'num']
df2 = df.iloc[df.index == 0]
```

This code will return you with two dataframes, separated by index.